# LWC datatable jest testing: row action menu items

Tags: lightning-datatable, lwc-jest

I would appreciate guidance on how to jest test row action menu items.
Are there any reference docs, clear examples or advice, please?
I am unable to find anything directly helpful.

SF general type code example :

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc'; 

const actions = [
    { label: 'Show details', name: 'show_details' },
    { label: 'Delete', name: 'delete' }
];

const columns = [
    // Other column data here
    { type: 'action', typeAttributes: { rowActions: actions, menuAlignment: 'left' } }
];

export default class DatatableExample extends LightningElement {
    data = [];
    columns = columns;

    handleRowAction(event) {
            const action = event.detail.action;
            const row = event.detail.row;
            switch (action.name) {
                case 'show_details':
                    this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
                         type: 'standard__recordPage',
                         attributes: {recordId: row.Id,actionName: 'view',},
                        });
                break;
                case 'delete':
                    this.deleteRow(row);
                break;
                default: 
                break;   
     }

    deleteRow(row){ 
          //code to delete row
     };

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe now that I only need to test **my code** not SF component functionality.
Apologies for the poor question.